# Facebook: Get user's friends' time-zones

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like my canvas application to obtain time-zones of my user's friends.

I tried doing it with the Graph API but all I can get is their names, locales and a few more (even when using the `access_token`).
When using FQL the `timezone` field is always empty.

1. Is there a way to achieve this?
2. If so, could you please point me in the right direction?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is not possible, only the following fields were retrieved when calling `$this->facebook->api("/friend_ID");`:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 
    [name] => 
    [first_name] => 
    [last_name] => 
    [link] => 
    [gender] => 
    [locale] => 
    [updated_time] => 
)
```

Now in the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/), the above fields are the fields marked `Publicly available`, in time the `timezone` field is `Available to everyone on Facebook` which sounds like the same but apparently it's not, anyway I've found this interesting [article](http://www.takwing.idv.hk/blog/2010/12/22/differenc-between-publicly-available-available-to-everyone-on-facebook/) for a moderator on the facebook forums (not a developer!!)

Also tried the old rest lib, first get a list of your [friends](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/friends.get/) from the console and then add your ID and put them in the test console of the [users.getinfo](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/users.getinfo/) method, UIDs looks like `your_id,friend_id,friend_id,friend_id,friend_id` and fields `timezone` you'll only get **your** timezone.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
That's what I thought. However, `link` and `last_updated` fields are marked as _Available to everyone on Facebook_, not _Publicly Available_... They are inconsistent.
I guess I'll use the bugzilla and see what Facebook say